# Nested lists toggle visibility and :hover effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a section of navigation that contains menu items that you can click to see a list of other menu items which you can then click on to navigate. So far I have tried using `<ul> & <li>` which has resulted in this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image"/></a>
        <p>Directories</p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Test Text 1</li>
            <li>Test Text 2</li>
            <li>Test Text 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image"/></a>
        <p>Contracts</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image"/></a>
        <p>Processes</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image"/></a>
        <p>Filing</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image"/></a>
        <p>My Profile</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

This is creating a few issues for me. Firstly, I am not sure how to code this so that when the user clicks on `Directories` the `ul` nested inside is then visible.

Also, another issue with this is that it treats the `Directories` list and the `<ul>` inside the `Directories` list as one itme, meaning that the `:hover` effect is applied to all instead of to each individual item.

Is there a way I can A) toggle the nested list to show and hide on the click of the `Directories` `<li>` item and B) Treat the nested list separately so that the `:hover` effect is applied independently to both parent list and nested list.

Comment: We need your CSS and JavaScript to help you. Can you please make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
$("p").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").find("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

`closest()` will get you the parent li

Then traverse to the child ul using `find("ul")`

Answer (score 0):

a)  if you use jquery this help will you.

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.sub-menu').toggle();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu{
display:none}



.list-unstyled >li >a:hover{
background:blue;
color:white}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li id=toggle>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image" /></a>
    <p>Directories</p>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Test Text 1</li>
      <li>Test Text 2</li>
      <li>Test Text 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image" /></a>
    <p>Contracts</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image" /></a>
    <p>Processes</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image" /></a>
    <p>Filing</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Home.png" alt="home image" /></a>
    <p>My Profile</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```